# why is one for-loop faster than the other even though they do the "same"?

Tags: java

**Situation:** Two for-loops assign values to an int[][] Array.

- First Loop: Adds the outer counter to the inner Array
- Second Loop: Adds the outer counter to the outer Array

Here is the Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] array = new int[4096][4096];

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i<4096;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<4096;j++){
            array[i][j] = i*4096+j;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("First loop: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i<4096;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<4096;j++){
            array[j][i] = i*4096+j;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Second loop: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}
```

Output:

```
First loop: 25
Second loop: 83
```

**Question:** Why is one faster than the other ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30160422/1079354 (I'm somewhat reluctant to use my Mjolnir here since they're very similar questions, but not asking this in the same way.)

Comment: Cache locality. In the first case the access is mostly sequential, while for the other it flips between many possibly distant positions.

Comment: Thanks, the Mjolnir question answered it basically. Sorry for the duplicate, wasn't sure what to google.

Comment: Don't feel too bad.  So since you've accepted the duplicate of the C question, does the Java question not apply or is it not as sufficient?

Comment: The answer in the link is sufficient, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java stores 2D arrays as a list of contiguous 1D arrays (row-major format), hence moving in row-major format will take less time.